# How to show nested submenus on top of a menu in JQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery Mobile Navbar. I want the submenus to be shown on top of the corresponding menu rather than below it. The following code shows that the submenus "Test 1" and "Test 2" are shown under "Less" but I want them to be shown on top of it. Is this possible?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
           <li><a href="#" data-icon="plus">More</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" data-icon="minus">Less</a>
             <ul>
               <li><a href="#" data-icon="minus">Test 1</a>
             </ul>
             <ul>
               <li><a href="#" data-icon="minus">Test 2</a>
             </ul>
           </li>

      </ul>

    </div>

  </div>

</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you also post an image with the desired effect?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want them on top of 'Less' button as shown in new uploaded image

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962418/how-to-make-css-for-navbar-jquery-mobile-bottom-up-submenu-automatic